# Add user profile to request.user

Tags: python, django

I have multiple `User` Types which I represent by user profiles in the form of a model:

- Student
- Teacher

I need access to the specific user profile on every request.
To avoid executing an extra query every time I would like to add directly a `select_related` to the `request.user` object.

I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. Does anyone know the best way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interesting question. Looking at the source code of [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L16) and [auth.get_user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L165) it seems that only thing you'll need to do will be to implement and use you own authentication backend. If you don't use any other custom backend features, you can subclass the [ModelBackend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L11), overriding only the `get_user` method to suit your needs:

```
class MyModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.select_related("profile").get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

Of course, you'll need to add it to your settings [AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS).

Comment: Interesting Answer.

Comment: Great answer, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: More info: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser